# Can't log in to Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azureportal

I can't authenticate into [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) on my home desktop (Windows 10 Home). It just hangs with the following icon until I eventually get redirected to the [error timeout page](https://portal.azure.com/Error/PageLoadTimeout).

[image]

Interestingly I can still log into Office 365 and Azure DevOps, and I can also log in to the Azure Portal on my laptop. This makes me think it's related to my comp and not my Azure account.

I've tried the following:

- Clearing cache, cookies, etc (in Chrome - latest version - Version 92.0.4515.107)
- incognito mode (in Chrome)
- different browsers - Edge/Opera
- flushing dns
- turning comp on/off

If I check the browser console in Chrome, there's a bunch of errors when trying to open the Azure portal e.g.

[image]

first couple errors in the console are:

```
MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 1 MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter: {"message":"Request Error","responseHeaders":"cache-control: no-cache\r\ncontent-type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\ndate: Sun, 25 Jul 2021 23:13:32 GMT\r\nexpires: -1\r\nnel: {\"report_to\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":86400,\"success_fraction\":0.001,\"failure_fraction\":1.0}\r\npragma: no-cache\r\nreport-to: {\"group\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":86400,\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https://eafc.nelreports.net/api/report?cat=aportal\"}]}\r\nstrict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains\r\nx-content-type-options: nosniff\r\nx-ms-version: 8.75.0.5 (production#6db687bbc5.210712-1125) Signed\r\nx-ua-compatible: IE=edge\r\nx-xss-protection: 1; mode=block\r\n","responseText":"{\"Message\":\"There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments.\",\"HttpStatusCode\":\"InternalServerError\",\"XMsServerRequestId\":null,\"StackTrace\":null}","status":500,"statusText":"","uri":"/api/Portal/GetEarlyUserData?feature.internalgraphapiversion=true&feature.iris=true&feature.irismessagelimit=1&feature.showservicehealthalerts=true"}
```

```
MsPortalImpl/Services/Services.Settings 1 Services.Settings: _errorData: undefined
_sourceErrorLevel: undefined
baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: undefined
errorLevel: 2
extension: fx
handled: undefined
innerErrors: ["message: {\"message\":\"Request Error\",\"responseHeaders\":\"cache-control: no-cache\\r\\ncontent-type: application/json; charset=utf-8\\r\\ndate: Sun, 25 Jul 2021 23:13:32 GMT\\r\\nexpires: -1\\r\\nnel: {\\\"report_to\\\":\\\"network-errors\\\",\\\"max_age\\\":86400,\\\"success_fraction\\\":0.001,\\\"failure_fraction\\\":1.0}\\r\\npragma: no-cache\\r\\nreport-to: {\\\"group\\\":\\\"network-errors\\\",\\\"max_age\\\":86400,\\\"endpoints\\\":[{\\\"url\\\":\\\"https://eafc.nelreports.net/api/report?cat=aportal\\\"}]}\\r\\nstrict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains\\r\\nx-content-type-options: nosniff\\r\\nx-ms-version: 8.75.0.5 (production#6db687bbc5.210712-1125) Signed\\r\\nx-ua-compatible: IE=edge\\r\\nx-xss-protection: 1; mode=block\\r\\n\",\"responseText\":\"{\\\"Message\\\":\\\"There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments.\\\",\\\"HttpStatusCode\\\":\\\"InternalServerError\\\",\\\"XMsServerRequestId\\\":null,\\\"StackTrace\\\":null}\",\"status\":500,\"statusText\":\"\",\"uri\":\"/api/Portal/GetEarlyUserData?feature.internalgraphapiversion=true&feature.iris=true&feature.irismessagelimit=1&feature.showservicehealthalerts=true\"}\r\nstack: Error: {\"message\":\"Request Error\",\"responseHeaders\":\"cache-control: no-cache\\r\\ncontent-type: application/json; charset=utf-8\\r\\ndate: Sun, 25 Jul 2021 23:13:32 GMT\\r\\nexpires: -1\\r\\nnel: {\\\"report_to\\\":\\\"network-errors\\\",\\\"max_age\\\":86400,\\\"success_fraction\\\":0.001,\\\"failure_fraction\\\":1.0}\\r\\npragma: no-cache\\r\\nreport-to: {\\\"group\\\":\\\"network-errors\\\",\\\"max_age\\\":86400,\\\"endpoints\\\":[{\\\"url\\\":\\\"https://eafc.nelreports.net/api/report?cat=aportal\\\"}]}\\r\\nstrict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains\\r\\nx-content-type-options: nosniff\\r\\nx-ms-version: 8.75.0.5 (production#6db687bbc5.210712-1125) Signed\\r\\nx-ua-compatible: IE=edge\\r\\nx-xss-protection: 1; mode=block\\r\\n\",\"responseText\":\"{\\\"Message\\\":\\\"There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments.\\\",\\\"HttpStatusCode\\\":\\\"InternalServerError\\\",\\\"XMsServerRequestId\\\":null,\\\"StackTrace\\\":null}\",\"status\":500,\"statusText\":\"\",\"uri\":\"/api/Portal/GetEarlyUserData?feature.internalgraphapiversion=true&feature.iris=true&feature.irismessagelimit=1&feature.showservicehealthalerts=true\"}\n    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://portal.azure.com/?bundlingKind=DefaultPartitioner&configHash=3HVigcPjEhD-&env=portal&helppanenewdesign=true&helppanevmproblemcards=false&l=en.en-us&moveresourcesreact=true&pageVersion=8.75.0.566875.210712-1125:12:363)\r\n"]
message: Early Failed to preload stores.
name: Error
source: undefined
stack: Error: Early Failed to preload stores.
    at new t (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/LIXabXGijvQo.js:83:882)
    at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/IUr50ifbdDUb.js:62:6538
timestamp: 734.0999999642372
type: MsPortalFx.Errors.Error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am having the same issue and have figured out what was causing it. My antivirus, I use Free BitDefender. When I disable the protection I can then access azure.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround, use Brave browser. Chrome, Edge, Firefox or Opera have the problem.

Comment: Thanks - this worked. Upvoted, but not marked as answer as it's more of a work around... cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing exactly the same thing. I can log in fine on other computers and my mobile

Answer (score 0):

Running https://portal.azure.com/selfhelp can possibly help you diagnose issues that would cause an issue like this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran the self help, but it said "All checks have succeeded", but I still can't get into the Azure portal.